# Incrementally pixilized video game faces from a real face

Tags: adobe-photoshop, photo-editing

My input is a photo of a real face: png with greenscreen background.

My intended output is a (late 90's) video-game looking characterization of that face.

I also want to save a few of the intermediate steps to show the transition.

This is similar to what I want to achieve, but the intermediate steps seem a bit abrupt; I'm aiming for something a bit smoother.

[image]

### Question

How can I generate a pixel-sparse, somewhat convincing representation of a real face using built-in photoshop features?

**Note:** My sketching/digital sketching is poor, so I must rely on automated features. However, it would be acceptable if I have to put in a few cosmetic touches by hand for the final result.

Comment: You, hopefully, realize that artists have jobs for a reason.

Comment: As an avid Photosohop user I would suggest using blender. There is a nifty way to pixelate objects (althought I don't know if it works on flat pictures) https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=AQcovwUHMf0

Comment: @SZCZERZOKŁY A bit taken aback when he said: "Let's have a moment of silence for pixel artists... never mind, **** those guys." hahaha. Interesting process he used, probably too technical for my skill level, but thanks for the recommendation!